# primefaces datatable with multiple row selection

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to select multiple rows from a primefaces datatable, i followed the examples in the showcase , but no results

here is my XHTML:

```
<p:dataTable id="tabJob" var="contenuJob" value="#{templateBean.contenuJob}" selection="#{templateBean.selectedRows}" 
rowKey="#{templateBean.idJob}" style="margin-bottom:0"
scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" >

                        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center" />
                 <f:facet name="header">  
                    selectionner les colonnes
                  </f:facet>  

                <p:column headerText="#" style="width:3%"> #{rowIndex+1}</p:column>
                <p:columns value="#{templateBean.colonnes}" var="colonnes" columnIndexVar="ind" id="col#{ind}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                              <h:outputText value="#{colonnes}"/>
                        </f:facet>#{contenuJob[ind]}
                </p:columns>

                <f:facet name="footer">  
                    <p:commandButton process="tabJob" value="valider"    action="#{templateBean.validerSelection()}"/>  
                </f:facet>  

        </p:dataTable>
```

and in my ManagedBean:

```
private ArrayList<String> contenuJob,selectedRows;
.................
public String validerSelection(){


        System.out.println("size de selectedRows ::"+selectedRows.size());

        return null;
    }
```

and the s.o.p only returns 1 which is the size, i've already tried rowSelectMode="add" in the datatable but it didn't change a thing

Comment: I think you just need selectionMode="multiple" on the datatable

Comment: i already tried it but doesn't work

Comment: It seems to me templateBean.idJob will be constant for all the rows? Try rowKey="#{contenuJob}" instead. Plus the above suggestion

Comment: @jaqenh'ghar: please create it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said  **Jaqen H'ghar** , i changed to `rowKey="#{contenuJob}"` and it worked perfectly :)